# Why the gap statistic result is different in the R and Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, cluster-analysis

I tried to put the same data to do the gap statistic and want to get the optimal number of clusters. To examine the authenticity of the results, I tried to use different programs, `R` and `Matlab`, to do the same test. However, the results in `R` and `Matlab` are different from each other. The optimal number of clusters in `R` is 40, however, in `Matlab` is 6. I have tried to check every parameters and adjustment them to make all parameters are the same but still get the different results.

Is there still some detail that I missed? or the different results in different programs is in reason?
I have been troubled by this question for a long time. If you can help me, I will thank you very much.

This is the input data `gaptest` and the cluster method is `pam`

```
           X1          X2
1   0.6351928  -0.7824029
2   0.6401326  -0.7919060
3   0.6427007  -0.7968948
4   0.6558318  -0.8229245
5   0.6566169  -0.8245088
6   0.6680986  -0.8480393
7   0.6782454  -0.8693981
8   0.6796789  -0.8724580
9   0.7115760  -0.9431477
10  0.7133614  -0.9472431
11  0.7296727  -0.9852485
12  0.8195850  -1.2030732
13  0.8470816  -1.2677628
14  0.8491237  -1.2724711
15  0.9787868  -1.5406940
16  1.0200572  -1.6149679
17  1.0680393  -1.6964657
18  1.0776983  -1.7123423
19  1.0944731  -1.7395482
20  1.0968986  -1.7434456
21  1.1069733  -1.7595397
22  1.1134140  -1.7697527
23  1.1464978  -1.8213617
24  1.2733486  -2.0097707
25  1.3603164  -2.1343635
26  1.5108690  -2.3507509
27  1.7984058  -2.8258020
28  1.8317105  -2.8951666
29  1.9689162  -3.3205491
30  1.9830438  -3.6912299
31  1.8931125  -4.0746001
32  7.0844451 -12.5712374
33  7.0636832 -12.5987628
34  6.9238601 -12.7901880
35  6.8664584 -12.8743234
36  6.8151738 -12.9560336
37  7.1884836 -12.8093261
38  7.4338566 -12.6135888
39  7.6658285  -8.5133002
40  7.6070872  -8.4042949
41  7.6053719  -8.4004027
42  8.3855195  -8.0055749
43  8.5990981  -8.0174662
44 10.3757387  -8.3280635
45 10.4124935  -8.3389941
46 10.4836669  -8.3608685
47 10.8223695  -8.4792392
48 10.9421194  -8.5275618
```

code in `matlab`

```
myfunc=@(x,k) kmedoids(x,k,'Algorithm','pam','Start','sample');
gap1=evalclusters(gaptest,myfunc,'gap','KList',[1:length(gaptest)],'B',200,'SearchMethod','firstMaxSE','ReferenceDistribution','PCA');
```

plot result in `Matlab`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPtqs.png)

code in `R`

```
clusGap(gaptest,pam,K.max=47,B=200,verbose=TRUE)
```

result in `R`

```
clusGap(x = gaptest, FUNcluster = pam, K.max = 47, B = 200, verbose = TRUE)
B=200 simulated reference sets, k = 1..47; spaceH0="scaledPCA"
 --> Number of clusters (method 'firstSEmax', SE.factor=1): 40
```

plot result in `R`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo764.jpg)

I tried to change the cluster method in `Matlab` and the optimal number is still 6. And the plots of the result in `R` and `Matlab` are look so similar. But the optimal number of clusters are still different.

Comment: The gap statistic is not really well defined. It involves the generation of "random" reference data sets, to check how much better the real data is clustered. But the exact procedure to generate appropriate sets is unclear. So likely neither k is "optimal".

Comment: It may be interesting to see the actual *plots* of the gap, and not some fairly useless table screenshot.

Comment: Also, your Matlab code doesn't use PAM, but median linkage, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because 'firstMaxSE' in MATLAB and 'firstSEmax' in R search for the optimal k in different ways.

From the documentation (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/evalclusters.html#shared-criterion and https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.1.0/topics/clusGap)

'firstMaxSE' in MATLAB searches for the first k such that Gap(k)≥Gap(k+1)−SE(k+1) is satisfied. Looking at your first plot, this seems to be satisfied at k=6. In R, the equivalent option is "Tibs2001SEmax" rather than "firstSEmax".

"firstSEmax" in R searches for the location of the first value which is not smaller than the first local maximum, minus the corresponding SE factor. The first local maximum occurs much later than 6 in the k range, thus "firstSEmax" returns 40 as the optimal number of clusters.

The names of these options may be a little confusing, since they sound almost the same but refer to different things. If you instead try to use "Tibs2001SEmax" in R I think your result may agree with the output from MATLAB.